# $y^\prime=\sin^4y+\cos^4y,\,y(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

$y^\prime=\sin^4y+\cos^4y,\,y(0)=1$

I have to find the maximal definition range such that the Existence and Unity theorem exists.

Denote $f(x,y)=\sin^4y+\cos^4y$

Let $D=\{ (x,y) | |x|<a , |y-1|<b \}$

$|f(x,y)|=|\sin^4y+\cos^4y|\leq |\sin^4y|+|\cos^4y|\leq1$

$|f_y|=|4\sin^3(y)\cos(y)-4\cos^3(y)\sin(y)|\leq |4\sin^3(y)\cos(y)|+|4\cos^3(y)\sin(y)|\leq8$

Then $M=1 , \alpha=\min\{ a,\frac{b}{M}\}=\min\{ a,b\}$

Then we can take each $\alpha \in (-\infty,\infty)$.

The  definition range is $(-\infty,\infty)$

Is my solution correct ?

Feedback is welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, your conclusion is correct. Because $M=1$ is valid globally, the solution can grow at most linearly and thus has no singularities at finite time.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks ! appreciate!